# Extension on Python Lambda capability

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I asked for assistance creating a Python Lambda function capable of assignments and multi-line lambdas [in this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194735/a-less-limited-python-lambda).  Following @l0b0's suggestions, I realized that it was better constructed as a class.

There is a security risk associated with eval or exec and input strings as well as an increased difficulty debugging code but I wanted a more capable lambda for functional experiments.  This is probably unsuitable for production code.

Print will provide a code string that can be executed if you add the arguments.

Any suggestions for further improvements would be appreciated.

```
class lambda_():
    """
    Creates an executable anonymous function supporting multiple line and assignments.
    For one line the form is λ("parameters : code incl assignment")(*arguments) 
      and the first exepression is assigned to rtrn which is returned
    For multiline, use triple quotes with the parameters on the first line,
      the : is followed directly by a line feed and then the code
    Input:
        code in the form "x, y,...: return_value_expression; other code"
    Output is assigned to variable rtrn
    """
    def __init__(self, code):
        """
        self.parameters parses parameters (preceding the colon)
        self.code is the code after the colon with extra
          leading spaces removed from multiline lambdas
        """
        self.parameters = []
        val_idx = 0
        val_name = []
        i = 0
        if ":" in code:
            for i, c in enumerate(code):  # loop until the : that ends parameters
                if c in ",:":
                    if val_name:
                        self.parameters.append(''.join(val_name))
                        val_name = []
                        val_idx += 1
                    if c == ":":
                        break
                elif c != " ":
                    val_name.append(c)
        # self.code sets rtrn = None for multiline or sets rtrn = first expression for
        #    single line unless :: (used if first expression can't be evaluated)
        if code[i+1] != "\n":  # single line,
            if code[i+1] != ":":
                if code[i] != ":":
                    self.code = ''.join(("rtrn = ", code))
                else:
                    self.code = ''.join(("rtrn = ", code[i+1:]))
            else:
                self.code = ''.join(("rtrn = None; ", code[i+2:]))
        else:  # multiline
            # wont run if excess leading spaces so remove them
            lead = 0
            code_ = code[i+1:]
            while code_[lead+1] == " ":  # how many on 1st line?
                lead += 1
            for i in range(1, len(code_)):  # remove that on all lines
                if code_[i-1: i+1] == "\n ":
                    code_ = code_[: i] + code_[i+lead:]
            self.code = "rtrn = None" + "\n" + code_  # executable code

    def __call__(self, *args):
        """ 
        All arguments are declared global as listcomps etc don't create closure
        when called using exec, so first declare parameters & rtrn as globals,
        then collect parameter=value pairs in assignments.
        Multiline will return None unless you assign rtrn a value.
        """
        define_globals = ', '.join(["global rtrn"] + self.parameters)
        assign = '; '.join([' = '.join((p, str(args[i])))
                            for i, p in enumerate(self.parameters)])
        exec('; '.join((define_globals, assign if assign else "pass", self.code)))
        return rtrn

    def __str__(self):
        args = ["??" for _ in self.parameters] 
        define_globals = ', '.join(["global rtrn"] + self.parameters)
        assign = '; '.join([' = '.join((p, str(args[i])))
                            for i, p in enumerate(self.parameters)])
        return '; '.join((define_globals, assign if assign else "pass", self.code))

λ = lambda_  # rebind to linux ctrl+shift+u 03BB
```

**Examples:**

```
print(
    λ("""var:
         for i in range(var):
             print(i, end = ",")
             print(' ', end='')
             if i == var - 1:
                 print(var)
         print(var)
         rtrn = [i for i in range(var, 0, -1)]
    """)(5)
)

print(λ("x: [x*i for i in range(x)]; print('Final:', rtrn[-1])")(3))

print(λ("x, y:: from math import cos, sin; rtrn = cos(x) + sin(y)")(3, 5))

def applyToEach(L, f):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = f(L[i])

testList = [1, -4, 8, -9]
apply_to_each(testList, λ("x: x if x >= 0 else -x"))
print(testList, "\n")

multiline = λ("""var:
         for i in range(var):
             print(i, end = ",")
             print(' ', end='')
             if i == var - 1:
                 print(var)
         print(var)
         rtrn = [i for i in range(var, 0, -1)]
    """)

print("Multiline lambda") ; print(multiline)

p_lambda = λ('print("value")')

print("parameterless lambda") ; print(p_lambda)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend that you adopt some sort of testing framework for your tests instead of having a stand alone script. There are quite a few options out there. For instance, [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html). I would read up on how to write tests for `pytest` and in particular have a look at [how to capture IO](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html) since a lot of your tests depend on it.

I would also recommend you give more descriptive names to your tests instead of, for example, `test_print_1` and `test_print_2` I would try to explain what the particular test does. So in the case of `test_print_1` and `test_print_2` what particular case is each one trying to break?

Finally, you should look at [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), functions should have `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`. So, for example, `applyToEach` becomes `apply_to_each`.

Also, classes typically use `CapWords` convention, however, because you are trying to emulate the `lambda` keyword, using `lambda_` is probably a reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Dair.  

I should relabel them.  They're not rigorous tests, just something so that anyone wanting to try the code wouldn't have to do everything themselves.

I use snake but the function you mention is from a famous Python MOOC and I just copied the form.  I seem to recall PEP 8 permitted that but, I agree that snake's nicer: the Professors had clearly spent too much time with Scheme.  I might change it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

*I'll just leave this one behind for anyone interested in Python lambda variations (please ignore PEP8 violations etc, it's just for fun if anyone wants it).*

```
def λλ(s):
    """
    Anonymous function:  λ("args: code incl assignment")(vals *t)  
    Input:
        s = "parameters : code bound to z"
        parameters are single characters separated by ' ' or ','
        a variable length argument *t (for tuple)
        parameter names bound to the args t[0], t[1], ... 
        remaining elements of the args go into t
    Output is assigned to variable z
    """
    def build_lambda(*t, cpy=[0]):
        params = [c for c in s if c not in ', ' and (cpy if c != ':' else cpy.pop())]
        assi = [c + '=' + str(t[i: i+1][0]) for i, c in enumerate(params)]
        assigns = "; ".join(assi + [''.join(('t=t[', str(len(assi)), ':]'))])
        globls = ', '.join(("global z", *params))
        exec('; '.join((globls, assigns, ''.join(('z =', s[s.index(":")+1:])))))
        return z
    return build_lambda
```